# Understanding a trailing を in this song

Tags: particle-を, song-lyrics

Going through the song 幻愛遊戯｛げんあいゆうぎ｝ by GARNiDELiA, and three lines in I'm stuck.

The first four lines are relevant

> ちょいとそこのヒト　おいでなさい
>
> 私とイイこといたしませんか？
>
> 一期一会のひと時を
>
> 忘れられぬ瞬間｛とき｝にしてあげるわ

The first two lines are fine, but the third I'm not sure about. If it was

> 一期一会のひと時よ

Then I feel like I could translate it as "It's a one-in-a-lifetime moment," or something, but with the を at the end I'm wondering what's omitted.

I don't think it connects to the fourth line because that line seems complete, "I'm make it an unforgettable time for you."

I found [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57005/help-understanding-trailing-%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%82%92-in-song-lyrics), so maybe this を is similar and expresses some emotion?

Comment: Can the humble verb いたす be used with people other than yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the 3rd line connects to the 4th line to comprise a full sentence. Its basic structure is AをBにしてあげる = *I will make A B/turn A into B for you*.

Maybe slightly off the dictionary meaning, but 一期一会のひととき has the connotation of *one-off*, so the two lines mean *I will turn this one-off meeting into an unforgettable moment for you*.

Comment: Makes sense to me, thank you. Also what do you think about いたす being used in the 2nd line? Wouldn't なさる be expected since the sentence is directed at someone else?

Comment: @OtheJared Neutrally, it should be [㋑「する」の丁寧語](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%87%B4%E3%81%99/), not the humble form. But I guess, from the [mv](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQnht4bWmxw), it kind of related to the slangy erotic sense as well (see e.g. [here](https://kimu3.net/20170608/8018), ). The whole part sounds like inviting a one night stand.